# Displaying columns data in PHP search

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL table called products and in this table I have data:

```
id | category | product1 | price1 | discount1 | product2 | price2 | discount2 | product3 | price3 |discount3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | Meat    | Pork 1kg | 3.99   | -30%    | Lamb 1kg    | 5.94 | -25%      | Ham 200g    | 1.99 | -10% |
| 2 | Fruit   | Apple 1kg| 1.25   | -32%    | Banana 1 kg | 0.99 | -15%      | Melon 1 kg  | 0.79 | -12% |
```

PHP search script I have looks like this:

```
//-query the database table
$sql="SELECT id, category, product1, price1, discount1, 
product2, price2, discount2, product3, price3, discount3 
FROM products 
WHERE 
product1 LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR 
price1 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
discount1 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
product2 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
price2 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
discount2 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
product3 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
price3 LIKE '%" . $name ."%' OR 
discount3 LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";

//-run the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//-create while loop and loop through result set
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$id=$row['id'];
$category =$row['category'];
$product1=$row['product1'];
$price1=$row['price1'];
$discount1=$row['discount1'];
$product2=$row['product2'];
$price2=$row['price2'];
$discount2=$row['discount2'];
$product3=$row['product3'];
$price3=$row['price3'];
$discount3=$row['discount3'];

//-display the result of the array

echo "<ul>\n"; 
echo  "<li>" . $id . "</li>\n"; 
echo "<li>" . $category . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $product1 . "</li>\n"; 
echo "<li>" . $price1 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $discount1 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $product2 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $price2 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $discount2 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $product3 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $price3 . "</li>\n";
echo "<li>" . $discount3 . "</li>\n";
echo "</ul>";
}
```

The problem is that when I search for let's say Apple, Banana and Melon are also displayed.

How can I make it to show only Apple and it's price and discount when searching with keyword apple.

Comment: Why do you have 3 products in a single row ?

Comment: There is no reason for that. It was like this when I started to work on it. Is there a way to make search working with this structure?

Comment: Changing the structure will be easier than trying to work around it. In the short, but even more, in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DB structure is very odd, which is giving you this headache. Instead use normal relations.

Table categories

```
id  name
1   Meat
2   Fruit
```

Table products

```
id  category_id  product      price  discount
1   1            Pork 1kg     3.99   -30%
2   1            Lamb 1kg     5.94   -25%
3   1            Ham 200g     1.99   -10%
4   2            Apple 1kg    1.25   -32%
5   2            Banana 1 kg  0.99   -15%
6   2            Melon 1 kg   0.79   -12%
```

You can find a product (eg 'pork') using this query

```
SELECT product.*, category.name as category FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id WHERE product.name LIKE 'pork%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips to make code that is actually usable:

- Stop using `mysql` (it is deprecated) and start using `mysqli` and `PDO`.
- [Create a proper database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design). You need at least 2 tables in your situation - `categories` and `products`
- Look up some SQL tutorials. [Here's one](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) (you need to know how to use `JOIN`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right: You have into table columns with three products so in each row will be three products too. So Remove useless product2 and product3 (and their price etc.) and call only one product, which you want

Answer (score 0):

It is because, these products are in single row, add it as different row